# Java GUI create three JPanel in one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have a problem with Java GUI.

I want to create three `JPanel` instances which have size different in one `JFrame`. `JFrame` size 300x800 and `Panel1` 300x200, `Panel2` 300x100 and `Panel3` 300x500.  I want to add this panels under by under.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Already did. This is not a question, but more of a request.

Comment: How do you know what the panels' sizes are until you add components and `pack()` the containing `Window`?

Answer (score 8):

Use a `BorderLayout`<sup>1</sup>.

- Add `panel1` to the `NORTH`
- Add `panel2` to the `CENTER`
- Add `panel3` to the `SOUTH`

---

### E.G.

[image: Colored Panels]

Stretch your imagination that the heights are ten times bigger.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

class ColoredPanels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
                gui.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));

                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
                panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));
                panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
                gui.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,10));
                panel2.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                gui.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
                panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));
                panel3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                gui.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                // a frame would need pack() etc.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

#### BTW

1. Use `BorderLayout`, ..*or* `BoxLayout` as mentioned by Shakedown.
2. The panels as described will not fit into the frame at that size. A frame has its own decorations to account for (title bar, menus, borders etc.)
3. Please use `camelCase` for attribute names.

Comment: 1+ for a good suggestion.  Also don't set the size of the JFrame. Rather call `pack()` on it, and let the layout managers set the GUI size for you.

Comment: *"But panel's size different"*  And what does that mean in *your* head?  Could it be expanded to *"..so I cannot use BorderLayout"*?  If so, don't presume it will be read that way.  Be specific.

Comment: See the edit which shows how a `BorderLayout` can contain components of 3 (actually 5 with `EAST/WEST` constraints) different sizes.

Answer (score 4):

You can try sizing your panels with [`setPreferredSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) and company.
Then look into using a [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) on your frame, which will put your panels in a row or column.

Comment: 1+ for a good suggestion (although don't let Kleopatra see this as she will stress that one should override getPreferredSize rather than set it). Please see my comment on Andrew's post.